# Ionic (click) not working inside AlertController message Property

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to create a AlertController with a button inside `message` Property. And the (click) method doesn't work. Is there an alternative way? It renders the button component but can't use function.

```
async forgotPass() {
    const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
      header: "Forgot Password?",
      message: `Enter you email address to send a reset code.
         <a href="tel:+1-1800-555-5555" class="button button-positive">Call BKB</a> or
        <br/>
        <ion-button small (click)="navCtrl.navigateForward('forgot_password')">Enter Code</ion-button>  


        `,
      inputs: [
        {
          name: "email",
          type: "email",
          placeholder: "Email"
        }
      ],
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this but what about:

```
async forgotPass() {
    const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
      header: "Forgot Password?",
      message: `Enter you email address to send a reset code.
         <a href="tel:+1-1800-555-5555" class="button button-positive">Call BKB</a> or
        <br/>
        <ion-button small href="/forgot_password">Enter Code</ion-button>  


        `,
      inputs: [
        {
          name: "email",
          type: "email",
          placeholder: "Email"
        }
      ],
....
```